# How to force TypeScript to not compile to JS when I have an error in ts code, with tsconfig file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, tsconfig

### I didn't find in the default file: tsc --init

#### my config file

[github code](https://github.com/Alidhuniya/solo-learning-typescript-2021)

```
{
  "compilerOptions" : {
      "target": "ES3",
      "module": "ES2015",
      "declaration": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "rootDir": "./src",
      
      "watch": true
  },
  
 
  "include": [
      "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Specify `"noEmitOnError": true` [Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError)

Answer (score 6):

You need to add `noEmitOnError: true` in your tsconfig.json.

This flag controls if the typescript compiler should generate output files if any errors were reported. And by default it is false, meaning the compiler will still emit output files even when there are errors.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noEmitOnError

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.
I removed src in `tsconfig` after `compilerOptions` property. Then `tsc` command started showing type errors and imports.

Answer (score 0):

Add them to `config.json`, then append the `.ts` extension after every import.

```json
{
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true
}
```